# Bash script getting "No such file or directory" error?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I have a bash script named `args.sh`. It is just supposed to print out the argument passed in from the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Argument passed in: $1"
```

I have tried `chmod +x args.sh` but I get *`-bash: ./args: No such file or directory`*. I am doing this on a  mac.

How can I build an executable to invoke the script by calling `./args` (without the .sh file extension)?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Rename it to `args`.

Comment: If you're doing this on a mac, why did you tag your question `linux`?

Comment: You should show a `ls -Al a* *.sh` in the directory you are working from. Then, edit your question with the information.

Answer (score 1):

Executables on linux/unix don't have extensions. So if you've named your file "args.sh", then your executable is "args.sh".  Rename it to "args" if you want to call it with "./args".

The kernel then figures out how to load the executable by looking at the "magic string" at the beginning of the file. In this case, the magic string is "#!" (also known as a "shebang") which tells the kernel to use the executable on the rest of the line to run this script, in your case, "/bin/bash". Other magic strings will tell the kernel that it's a binary of ELF format or a.out format or what have you so that the kernel knows how to load them, or that it can't load them at all (e.g., if it's a RISC/6000 executable for AIX).